# Getter and setters to be made private or public?

Tags: java

I can really find any information on this..

Should getters and setter be made private or public?

```
import java.util.ArrayList;


public class StudentRecords {

  //private strings, ints and doubles
  private String name, subject;
  private int studentNo, level;
  private double avg, total;


  //constructor that sets name, studno...
  public StudentRecords(String name, int studentNo, String subject, int level, ArrayList<Double> grades){

    setName(name);
    setStudentNo(studentNo);
    setSubject(subject);
    setLevel(level);
    setAverage(grades);

  }



  public void setAverage(ArrayList<Double> grades) {

    for(int i = 0; i < grades.size(); i++){
        total += grades.get(i);
        avg = total/level;
    }
  }


  private void setName(String name){

    this.name = name;

  }

  private void setLevel(int level){

    this.level = level;

  }

  //public 
  public void setSubject(String subject){

    this.subject = subject;

  }

  private void setStudentNo(int studentNo){

    this.studentNo = studentNo;

  }


   public String toString() {
    return ("Student Name: "+ this.name +"\nStudent subject: "+this.subject + "\nStudent Number: " + this.studentNo + "\nStudent level: " + this.level + "\nAverage Grade: "+ avg +"\n\n");
   }

}
```

Comment: Please takes the time to format correctly...

Answer (score 4):

In general, they should be public. If they are private they can only be called from within your class and, since you already have access to the private variables within your class, are redundant. The point of them is to allow access to these variables to other, outside, objects.

Answer (score 0):

Getters and setters always must be public because when you try to use them in main class, if they are private you can't use so you can't set or get the variable you need

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your requirement and design. Generally, it getter and setters are made public to provide acess to other classes. Looking it, at your class and constructor , i believe you don't want to provide outside class acess, so **keepthem private**.

Now , then why to have getter and setter at all,as private you have already access with in the class. Reason is its better to access fields from getter & setter , so that if you want to put some particular validation or logic for updating values in future like studentNo should not be zero. Then you can do it at one place.

Again there is bargain , accessing variable directly will be faster than using getter and setter, so if you are preety sure, you are not going to have some validation in future, then don't create getter setter.

Answer (score -1):

Getter and Setter ment to be used to get! and edit the values of private member variables. setting them as private won't add any value because they will be not accessible from outside the class and accessible from inside without having the setters and getters at all.

Therefore, the answer is: **They must be public members.**

Comment: They only expected to be public in most cases. I can easily imagine a private setter if some checks are made on each value or synchronisation is used.

Comment: Likewise, protected getters and setters might be desired depending upon the situation. There is certainly nothing that requires them to be public.